# about GCC compiler to compile code blocks and visual studio

Tags: c++, c

I used GCC compiler to compile the code blocks editor files. I installed the visual studio editor for a purpose.

Do I need to install GCC compiler again for the visual studio code? Can I use the previous compiler for both code blocks and visual studio editor in same PC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the same compiler for two different IDEs.

Comment: but the path doesn't support , it asks netframework.exe file

Comment: the path is just a path and can't support anything. GCC also has nothing to do with .NET framework. It's your configuration that has problems. IDEs just call the compilers using some command line and you can also run those to compile code manually. Compilers don't know about IDEs so they can run anywhere